# How to get Reorder details of Stock Item from Tally using XML request

Tags: xml, integration, tally

I would like to get the reorder level, quantity and minimum order quantity of stock item from Tally prime using xml request.

When I tried using the variables like "ROSOrdLvl" and "ROSMinQty", which I found in tally developer for reorder level, I am getting error response as

```
<RESPONSE>
    <LINEERROR>Could not find Report &apos;ROSOrdLvl&apos;!</LINEERROR>
</RESPONSE>
```

same response received for minimum order quantity variable also

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning field name as report name, so you are getting that error

Since Reorder level, Quantity and minimum order quantity are present in Stock Item, first you need to Expand Stock Item Schema and search for properties you require

[image]

Then mention those property names in fetch list or Native list exmaple :

```
<!-- 
Generated Using TallyConnector - https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector
Incase of any errors raise a issue here - https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyXmlsGenerator

-->
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMSTOCKITEMCOL</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES />
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMSTOCKITEMCOL">
                        <TYPE>STOCKITEM</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>ReorderLevel,MinOrderPeriodLength,MinOrderPeriod,MinOrderAsHigher ,ReorderBase ,ReorderPeriodLength,ReorderPeriod</FETCH>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Xml Source  - https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt